# error while compiling - conversion from DWORD to LPCVOID

Tags: c++, g++

I found this code for injecting dll files and call functions from them. I got an exe and the source code. The exe is working but when i try to compile the source code i get this error:

```
LoadDll.cpp: In Funktion »bool ExecuteRemoteThread(HANDLE, BOOL, BOOL, wchar_t*, wchar_t*)«:
LoadDll.cpp:313:62: Fehler: ungültige Umwandlung von »DWORD (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)(RemoteThreadBlock*) {aka long unsigned int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)(RemoteThreadBlock*)}« in »LPCVOID {aka const void*}« [-fpermissive]
In file included from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/windows.h:50:0,
                 from LoadDll.cpp:16:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/winbase.h:2215:24: Fehler:   Argument 3 von »BOOL WriteProcessMemory(HANDLE, LPVOID, LPCVOID, SIZE_T, SIZE_T*)« wird initialisiert [-fpermissive]
```

The source code can be found at: https://pastebin.com/AuZpy57U

It seems like the error is in line 313

```
if ( ! WriteProcessMemory( hProcess, p, &RemoteThread, 0, 0 ) )
```

I hope you can help me compiling this.

Comment: What's the question title "error while compiling - WinMain@16 not found" got to do with anything described in the question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/22160071#22160071

Comment: Updated the title, sorry was a mistake

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Both suggested duplicates are unrelated to the question.

Comment: @Swordfish Feel free to ropen then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if ( ! WriteProcessMemory( hProcess, p, &RemoteThread, 0, 0 ) )
> ```

You have to cast the third parameter:

```
if ( !WriteProcessMemory( hProcess, p, reinterpret_cast<LPCVOID>(&RemoteThread), 0, 0 ) )
```

#### Update:

To get rid of `undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'` you should use

```
int main()
{
    int argc;
    wchar_t **argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);

    // ...
```

instead of

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    // ...
```

Comment: It seems like an syntax error (even if i change the paranthesis): LoadDll.cpp: In Funktion »bool ExecuteRemoteThread(HANDLE, BOOL, BOOL, wchar_t*, wchar_t*)«:
LoadDll.cpp:313:58: Fehler: expected type-specifier before »(« token
LoadDll.cpp:313:58: Fehler: expected »>« before »(« token
LoadDll.cpp:313:66: Fehler: expected primary-expression before »)« token

Comment: @PrinzPorno what syntax error. you said you fixed the brackets already.

Comment: No i tried to play around with the brackets (make it like in your answer now) but had no sucess :(

Comment: @PrinzPorno you won't have much luck learning C++ by trial and error. i've fixed the mistake in my answer.

Comment: I did it the exact same way as you.. now i get errors again like: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'. Sorry, to be honest for now i just want to compile this program. I still learn C++ but i am far away of understanding this code :(

Comment: @PrinzPorno I've updated my answer regarding "undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'".